# Roundcube customise SMTP_USER variable

Tags: php, roundcube

I have installed Roundcube webmail on my server, but I want to customise it a little but.

In the file config/defaults.inc.php, there is variable `$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';`

But I'd like to change this value, based on the value of `$_SESSION["username"];`, however the session is not started in the file, and only is in the index.php file.

I have tried setting `$config['smtp_user']` inside the index.php file, which sets it fine but it doesn't work when sending mail.

Is there a way I can change this value inside my `config/defaults.inc.php` or `config/config.inc.php` file and use the value from `$_SESSION["username"]`

Comment: Can you include your code in github or somewhere we can see it?

Comment: @user3585659 i'm trying to change the value of `$config['smtp_user']` by using a session variable but the session is not started in the file `defaults.inc.php` which contains `$config['smtp_user']`

Comment: Why not have a default value first, then when the session start you change the value. Something like `$config['smtp_user'] = $_SESSION['nameOfSession'] ? $_SESSION['nameOfSession'] : $yourDefaultValue`

Comment: I tried this yesterday actually in the index.php file, but it didn't seem to pickup the correct value. I'm not sure whether the `$config` vars are picked up somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You can start the session in a read-only mode and then get the username. With this solution, the session will get started in a `read-only mode` and then immediately closed after populating `$_SESSION`.

Add this to your `config.inc.php`:

```
session_start(['read_and_close' => true]);
$config['smtp_user'] = $_SESSION['username'] ?? '%u';
```

---

If you also want to modify the session (f.e. to only fill the username from session for one request), you can add this to your `config.inc.php` instead:

```
session_start();
$config['smtp_user'] = $_SESSION['username'] ?? '%u';
unset($_SESSION['username']);
session_write_close();
```